# Autoscaling to parent object within a ScrollViewer?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, scrollviewer

I am having an autoscaling issue with my pages. The pages are displayed within a ScrollViewer, which usually contains a column on the ~33% right and a grid on the ~66% left.

I want to only autoscale the grid's Height (ie. independantly from the column at the right), so that it stretches according the size of the window, ergo, the object that **contains** the ScrollViewer and not the ScrollViewer itself.

So far, I have not managed to put this idea into practice... How could I possibly explain to my xaml code that I want my grid to be stretched **in comparison to the ScrollViewer's "parent"** rather than the ScrollViwer itself?

Here is a code example of what I'm trying to accomplish here, if it make my case any simpler:

```
<Grid x:Name="Parent" MinHeight="400" MaxHeight="700">
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="Annoying ScrollViewer">
    <Grid x:Name="Page Content" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <!-- IN ANOTHER USERCONTROL FAR, FAR AWAY... -->
      <Grid x:Name="Inner Page Content">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="330" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="Right column" Grid.Column="1"></Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Left Grid" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="StretchToParentUserControl? Please?"></Grid>
      </Grid>
      <!-- BACK TO THE PARENT USERCONTROL -->
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:** I solved my problem by using the Window size in code-behind directly through **App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight** and substracting the height of the parent files's contents (it is static, so I can just type the numbers). Still, I won't put this solution as an answer since it does not actually answer the original question.

And here is a little drawing of what my (reached) goal was as requested (uh... just switch the words "left" and "right" in the picture) :
[image: Drawing]

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm having trouble visualizing your dilemma even with your little example. Mind drawing some squares in paint real quick to help visualize? I'm thinking its a simple fix but wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I thought of doing so but while I was doing it I thought of some way to avoid using VerticalAlignment. Here is the image anyway (edited in the question)

Comment: Oh ya, a quick fix for that would be to just add `Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=RightColumn}"` to the Left Grid. Glad you got your remedy. :)

Comment: Thanks :) but wouldn't that have just made the grid to the same length as the right column? My goal was to make it a different height (what I was aiming for is on the right of the picture)

Comment: Ya guess I had a blonde moment there and switched the two since the column titles were switched or something. In that case then ya all I would have done was ran the `ActualHeight` of the Left Column through a converter for the Right Column to add the additional height or thrown a negative `Margin` on it like `Margin="0,0,0,-100"` etc. Sorry about that. :)